# Assign employee to user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am a beginner in Django and trying to create a web application.
In this case I want to assign an employee to a user.
In the user form, the call is made to the employees who are active and who do not yet have assigned users.
The problem is that when making the call and listing the employees on the screen, it does not bring me the name of the employee, it only brings me: **Employee Object(8)**

My model(User)

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  employee = models.OneToOneField(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

  def __str__ (self):
    return '{}'.format(self.username,self.groups,self.active,self.employee)
```

My Form(User)

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):

  username = forms.CharField(label="User",
  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs{"class":"formcontrol"}))

  groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label="Rol",queryset=Group.objects.all(),
  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required=True)

  password1 = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
  password2 = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})

  employee = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.filter(user=None,active=True),
  widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        "username",
        "password1",
        "password2",
        "groups",
        "employee",
        #"active",
        ]
```

My model (Employee)

```
 class Employee(Person):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
           return'{}'.format(self.doc,self.address,self.email,self.phone,self.name,self.active)
```

Comment: Share your `Employee` model.

Comment: Are you using `{{form.as_p}}` in the template? Otherwise share your template.

Comment: It should be `return f"{self.name}"` in  `__str__()` of `Employee` model itself, again check below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982111/17562044) I edited it.

Comment: Yes in my template I am using {{form.as_p}}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that when making the call and listing the employees on the screen, it does not bring me the name of the employee, it only brings me: Employee Object(8).

Since you should return name of employee in the [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method of `Employee` model itself.

An example here:

```py
class Employee(Person):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset=Employee.objects.filter(user=None,active=True).values("name_field_from_table","other_field_if_you_want")
```